# BizTalk resources for very beginner?

Tags: reference, biztalk

This seems that very few resources are available to learn the BizTalk technology.

The books that are written are very complex in nature and do not provide any step by step practical implementation of the concepts .
For Ex : I am following this PDF book BizTalk 2010 Recipes (A problem Solution Approach) and in that the article Creating Soap Headers.
http://tutorial.wmlcloud.com/windows_server/BizTalk-2010-Recipes---Creating-SOAP-Header-Schemas.aspx

But it seems to be not complete, How can someone without knowledge can create the sample applications. All authors are assuming that you are expert and just want to revise the concept.

I am Struggling very hard to find any practical lab or practical demonstration which I can learn as very beginner of the Technology.

Anyone can share the links and resources here.

Comment: While this is definitely an off topic question, I'd strongly recommend going through the MSDN virtual labs: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amantaras/archive/2011/10/13/biztalk-2010-virtual-labs.aspx and then working through BizTalk Server Unleashed.  Starting with anything related to web services is more advanced and going to assume you know more of the basics already.

Comment: @DanField Unfortunately, BizTalk labs are no longer available on TechNet.

Comment: Wow, that must have happened very recently - I was walking a guy through them less than a month ago!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BizTalk probably has the steepest learning curve of any technology I've ever worked with. Creating SOAP headers and using web services are some of the more advanced concepts, and assumes you have a solid understanding of how the BizTalk message box works, and understand SOAP and XML web service technology (which is completely separate from BizTalk).

If you are only starting out, I would advise you start with the basic concepts. Create schema A; create schema B; create a map from schema A to schema B; use a receive location to pick up an XML file conforming to schema A from location A; validate the XML against schema A using a pipeline; use a send port to subscribe to the message and write it to location B.

CodeProject has loads of useful tutorials and sample projects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

A good resource to start off with might be the book:
(MCTS): Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010 (70-595) Certification Guide

Link (not affiliated): [http://www.amazon.com/MCTS-Microsoft-BizTalk-Server-Certification/dp/1849684928](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849684928)

Although this will certainly not be enough to become proficient in BizTalk applications, it will give you a pretty solid start. Please note that this involves BizTalk Server 2010, which has already been deprecated by BizTalk Server 2013 and BizTalk Server 2013 R2, which is - at the moment of writing - the latest version. 
It is expected that a new version "BizTalk Server 2016" (?) will be released this year (2016).

However, don't be alarmed, the basics of a BizTalk application (ports, pub/sub, orchestrations, etc)... haven't changed all that much since BizTalk 2004. It is now mainly about supportability of the latest versions of Windows (Server), SQL Server, .NET, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will surly use the book provided by you.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorials at MSDN start with the basic concepts:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560270.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/dd849956

What you're looking at, creating custom SOAP Headers, is not a beginner concept and in 15 years, I've never had to do that so...don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yaa Ok. I will refer this links. if soap are not used frequently then its OK for me as I am beginner.